# Batch names and send HTTP request using panda.Series and Spark UDF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column "names" and I want to create an HTTP POST request using these names in the payload.

```
# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

bearerToken = 'abc'
records = []

def insert(names):
    for name in names:
        fields = {"fields": {
                        "name":  name
                    }
        }
        records.append(fields)
    print(records)

    url = insertURL
    try:
        payload = json.dumps({
            "records": records
        })

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {bearerToken}'
        }
    
        response = requests.request(
            "POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        dataRes = response.json()
        return pd.Series(["Success"] * len(names))

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error Occurred:", e)

def main():
    match args.subparser:
        case 'Insert':
            # Create and initialize a Faker Generator
            fake = Faker()
            global bearerToken
            numberOfRecords = args.numberOfRecordsToBeInserted

            columns = ["seqno", "name"]
            data = []
            for i in range(numberOfRecords):
                data.append((i, fake.name()))

            df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data), schema=columns)
            call_udf = pandas_udf(insert, returnType=StringType())
            

            names_series = df.select("name").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
            names_df = spark.createDataFrame([(name,) for name in names_series], ["name"])
            
            # Apply the Pandas UDF to the names DataFrame
            result_df = names_df.withColumn("response", call_udf(col("name")))
            result_df.show(truncate=False)

        case _:
            print("Invalid operation")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This leads to successful insert of the names, however the `records` only contains a single name. The `print(records)` has this:

```
[{'fields': {'name': 'Jessica Moore'}}]                                         
[{'fields': {'name': 'Noah Crawford'}}]
[{'fields': {'name': 'Jessica Welch'}}]                                         
[{'fields': {'name': 'Rita Brown DDS'}}]
[{'fields': {'name': 'Ronald Saunders'}}]
```

rather than the expected:

```
[{'fields': {'name': 'Jessica Moore'}},{'fields': {'name': 'Noah Crawford'}},{'fields': {'name': 'Jessica Welch'}},{'fields': {'name': 'Rita Brown DDS'}},{'fields': {'name': 'Ronald Saunders'}}]
```

How do I change the above code to get it in this format?

[EDIT] Added a reproducible example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import argparse
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf
from faker import Faker
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import pandas as pd

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Program Arguments for Insert")

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser')

parser_1 = subparsers.add_parser(
    'Insert-Records', help='Insert Records')
parser_1.add_argument("--numberOfRecordsToBeInserted", type=int, default=500,
                      help="The number of records to be inserted into the newly created vault")

args = parser.parse_args()

def insert(names):
    records = []
    
    for name in names:
        fields = {"fields": {"name": name}}
        records.append(fields)
    print(records)

    return (pd.Series(["Success"] * len(names)))


def main():
    match args.subparser:
        case 'Insert-Records':
            # Create and initialize a Faker Generator
            fake = Faker()
            global numberOfRecords
            numberOfRecords = args.numberOfRecordsToBeInserted

            columns = ["seqno", "name"]
            data = []
            for i in range(numberOfRecords):
                data.append((i, fake.name()))

            df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data), schema=columns)
            call_udf = pandas_udf(insert, returnType=StringType())
            

            names_series = df.select("name").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
            names_df = spark.createDataFrame([(name,) for name in names_series], ["name"])
            
            # Apply the Pandas UDF to the names DataFrame
            result_df = names_df.withColumn("response", call_udf(col("name")))
            result_df.show(truncate=False)


        case _:
            print("Invalid operation")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Usage: `python3 example.py Insert-Records --numberOfRecordsToBeInserted 5`

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi, added a reproducible example showing how the for loop does not work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line to the above example got it working:
`names_df = names_df.repartition(1)`

This repartitions the data frame to a single partition before applying the `pandas_udf`